# lambda function to omit value on a list

Tags: recursion, lambda, racket

I am wondering if there is any way to write a lambda function(recursively?), that omits certain value(it's every occurence) on a given list?

I tried come up with an idea, but the whole thing breaks down - because we need to always specify a body of our lambda, because it is calculated at occurence place in code.

I thought it could be done by specifying lambda body with another lambda, but I have no clue on how to do it.

Comment: See the [Y combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Y_combinator).

Comment: Like [`remove*`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._remove%2A%29%29) and friends?

Answer (score 3):

I have a lambda -

```rkt
(lambda (x)
  ...)
```

But inside the `...` expression I would like to call it recursively. I know if I give the lambda a name, I can call it *by name*, but I want to recur without a name. Let's imagine another lambda that applies its argument to itself -

```rkt
(lambda (f) (f f))
```

Now let's apply it to our original lambda -

```rkt
((lambda (f) (f f))
 (lambda (x) ...))
```

Now `x` is a reference to itself! Ok, so how does that enable recursion? `x` is our lambda, and *when applied to itself* provides a mechanism for recursion -

```rkt
((lambda (f) (f f))
 (lambda (x) ;; x *is* this lambda
   (println "infinite recursion happening now...")
   (x x))) ;; apply x to itself to recur
```

```rkt
"infinite recursion happening now..."
"infinite recursion happening now..."
"infinite recursion happening now..."
"infinite recursion happening now..."
...
(ad infinitum)
```

So that's great and all, but how would we stop the infinite recursion? And more importantly, how can we pass arguments along the way?

As we saw `(x x)` drives the recursion. If we only recur under a *condition*, we can control when our procedure exits. Let's have our `(lambda (x) ...)` return another procedure, `(lambda (n) ...)` instead -

```rkt
((lambda (f) (f f))
 (lambda (x)
   (lambda (n)
     (if (zero? n)  ; condition
         ...        ; done
         (x x)))))  ; otherwise recur
```

However instead of immediately recurring `(x x)` will now return a procedure, `(lambda (n) ...)`, so we can apply it to an argument to pass along a new `n` value -

```rkt
((lambda (f) (f f))
 (lambda (x)
   (lambda (n)
     (if (zero? n)
         "done"
         (begin
           (printf "~a ...\n" n)
           ((x x)                 ; (x x) returns λn 
            (sub1 n)))))))        ; updated n
```

So to recap outer `λf` applies `λx` to itself, which now returns `λn`. Now we apply *that* to an argument and witness nameless, anonymous procedure recursion -

```rkt
(((lambda (f) (f f))
  (lambda (x)
    (lambda (n)
      (if (zero? n)
          "done"
          (begin
            (printf "~a ...\n" n)
            ((x x)
             (sub1 n)))))))
 5) ; apply the procedure to 5
```

```rkt
5 ...
4 ...
3 ...
2 ...
1 ...
done
```

**u combinator**

The combinator we wrote above is known as the **u combinator**

```rkt
(define u
  (lambda (f) (f f)))
```

We can rewrite our program using `u` below -

```
((u (lambda (x)            ; (u (lambda (x) ...))
      (lambda (n)
        (if (zero? n)
            "done"
            (begin
              (printf "~a ...\n" n)
              ((u x)                 ; (u x) to recur
               (sub1 n)))))))
 5)
```

**y combinator**

The `(x x)` and `(u x)` recursion mechanisms are a little weird though. It would be nice if we could pass a more suitable recursion mechanism to our lambda and recur directly using that parameter. This is the basis of the **y combinator** -

```rkt
(define y
  (lambda (f)
    (f (lambda (x)     ; rather than applying f to itself
         ((y f) x))))) ; provide a lambda, when applied, recurs
```

Below we name the parameter `recur`, but you can call it whatever you want -

```rkt
((y (lambda (recur)            ; (y (lambda (recur) ...))
      (lambda (n)
        (if (zero? n)
            "done"
            (begin
              (printf "~a ...\n" n)
              (recur (sub1 n))))))) ; apply recur to.. recur!
 5)
```

```rkt
5 ...
4 ...
3 ...
2 ...
1 ...
done
```

**in practice**

Let's see a slightly more sophisticated example. We can assign our `(y ...)` expression to a name, `factorial`, and call it repeatedly with different initial values for `n`. Note we are not recurring with the procedures *name*. The y-combinator provides the parameter for direct recursion -

```rkt
(define factorial
  (y (lambda (recur)    ; y provides recur
       (lambda (n)
         (if (zero? n)
             1
             (* n (recur (sub1 n))))))))  ; recur!

(factorial 10) ; initial n = 10
(factorial 20) ; initial n = 20
```

```rkt
3628800
2432902008176640000
```

To demonstrate another way to compute a factorial, we could use *another* curried parameter to track an accumulator over the course of the computation -

```rkt
(define factorial
  ((y (lambda (recur)
        (lambda (acc)     ; accumulator parameter
          (lambda (n)
            (if (zero? n)
                acc
                ((recur (* acc n)) (sub1 n))))))) ; recur with two arguments
   1)) ; initial acc = 1

(factorial 10) ; initial n = 10
(factorial 20) ; initial n = 20
```

```rkt
3628800
2432902008176640000
```

That `λrecur.λacc.λn. ...` is getting a bit hard to read. We can use `curry` to convert a multi-parameter procedure to its curried form -

```rkt
(define factorial
  ((y (curry (lambda (recur acc n) ; simplified
               (if (zero? n)
                   acc
                   ((recur (* acc n)) (sub1 n))))))
   1))
```

```rkt
(factorial 10)
(factorial 20)
```

```rkt
3628800
2432902008176640000
```

Similarly, we can improve `y` to provide a more ergonomic recursion mechanism that accepts multiple arguments -

```rkt
(define y
  (lambda (f)
    (f (lambda args   ; multiple args
         (apply (y f) args)))))   ; apply (y f) to args
```

Effortless recursion with multiple arguments -

```rkt
(define factorial
  ((y (curry (lambda (recur acc n)
               (if (zero? n)
                   acc
                   (recur (* acc n) (sub1 n)))))) ; simplified
   1))
```

```rkt
(factorial 10)
(factorial 20)
```

```rkt
3628800
2432902008176640000
```

**remove**

With these fundamentals in place, we can get to the meat of your question. We will write a `remove` procedure which accepts an element to remove `e`, and an input list `xs` -

```rkt
(define remove
  (y (curry (lambda (recur e xs)
              (cond ((null? xs)
                     null)
                    ((eq? e (car xs))
                     (recur e (cdr xs)))
                    (else
                     (cons (car xs)
                           (recur e (cdr xs)))))))))
```

```rkt
(remove 'q '(a b q c d q e q f q g q q h i q))
```

```rkt
'(a b c d e f g h i)
```

**more parameters**

There's no limit to the number of parameters your recursive lambda can use. Let's see `fibonacci` which uses two initial parameters, `a = 0` and `b = 1` and a third parameter `n`, to compute the *nth* term in the famous sequence -

```rkt
(define fibonacci
  ((y (curry (lambda (recur a b n) ; as number of parameters
               (if (zero? n)
                   a
                   (recur b (+ a b) (sub1 n)))))) ; ergonomic recursion
   0   ; initial a = 0
   1)) ; initial b = 1
```

The `n` argument is supplied at the call site -

```rkt
(fibonacci 10) ; initial n = 10
(fibonacci 100) ; initial n = 100
```

```rkt
55
354224848179261915075
```

**going deeper**

Did you notice the Y-combinator above uses its own name `y` in its definition? We can rewrite it using the U-combinator, such that no definition refers to itself by name -

```rkt
(define u
  (lambda (f) (f f)))

(define y
  (u (lambda (h)   ; now defined in terms of U
       (lambda (f)
         (f (lambda args
              (apply ((u h) f) args))))))) ; no reference to Y
```

This `y` works the same as above, but no longer refers to itself by its name. Let's see some more sophisticated functions now. Here's a `range` function that builds a list from `min` to `max` -

```rkt
(define range
  (y (curry (lambda (recur min max)
              (if (> min max)
                  null
                  (cons min (recur (add1 min) max)))))))
```

```rkt
(range 5 10)
```

```rkt
'(5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

Here's a `foldr` procedure to fold a list from right to left with a user-supplied function `f`, an initial accumulator `init`, and an input list, `xs` -

```rkt
(define foldr
  (y (curry (lambda (recur f init xs)
              (if (null? xs)
                  init
                  (f (car xs)
                     (recur f init (cdr xs))))))))
```

```rkt
(foldr + 0 (range 5 10))
```

```rkt
45
```

We could partially apply `foldr` with `+` and `0` to define `sum` -

```rkt
(define sum
  (foldr + 0))
```

```rkt
(sum (range 5 10))
```

```rkt
45
```

We could define a higher-order `map` that maps an input list with a user-supplied function `f`, using `foldr` behind the scenes -

```rkt
(define map
  (curry (lambda (f xs)
           (foldr (lambda (x acc) (cons (f x) acc))
                  null
                  xs))))
```

```rkt
(map (lambda (x) (* 100 x))
     (range 5 10))
```

```
'(500 600 700 800 900 1000)
```

Finally we can see all of these expressions can be combined. Everything accomplished using nameless recursion!

```rkt
(sum (map (lambda (x) (* 100 x))
          (range 5 10)))
```

```rkt
4500
```

**remarks**

It can be challenging to reduce programming concepts to simple forms. To develop the capacity for thinking about programs like this, I strongly suggest the study of [**lambda calculus**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus). In this tiny model of computation, there are only three expressions to learn -

1. Variables, such as `x` or `y`
2. Abstraction, with a *single* parameter `(lambda (z) ...)` where `...` is a *single* expression
3. Application, `(f w)` where `f` is any lambda and `w` is any expression

These 3 components make up a universal model of computation that can simulate any Turing machine. Introduced by Alonzo Church in the 1930's, it serves as the theoretical foundation for functional programming style. Languages like Scheme and Racket were heavily influenced and embrace functional disciplines with a passion.

Learning to build things from the smallest, most primitive components can help you establish an insight and appreciation for higher level language features and give you the understanding and confidence necessary to design whatever you can imagine.