# What is (Y Y), the Y-combinator applied to itself?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, scheme, lambda-calculus, y-combinator

In Chapter 9 of *The Little Schemer*, the authors introduce the Y-combinator and the penultimate question asks: "What is `(Y Y)`". They answer: "Who knows, but it works very hard."

I tried reasoning about it and had a hard time. I assume this just causes an infinite loop, but maybe I am missing something. Are higher-order fixed-point combinators even interesting?

The book defines the Y-combinator as:

```scheme
(define Y
  (lambda(le)
    ((lambda(f) (f f))
     (lambda(f)
       (le (lambda(x) ((f f) x)))))))
```

However, using a let-binding is clearer, for me:

```scheme
(define Y (lambda(exp)
            (let ([a (lambda(f)
                       (exp (lambda(x) ( (f f) x))))])
        
      (a a))))
```

and simulating the length function works fine.

```scheme
((Y (lambda(s)
     (lambda(lat)
       (cond
         ((null? lat) 0)
         (else (add1 (s (cdr lat)))))))) '(1 2 4))
```

=> 3

---

When I try to evaluate `(Y Y)` in the Dr Racket IDE, the program crashes and runs out of memory.
How could I step through and reason about `(Y Y)` where I define Y using the let-binding above?

Comment: I think that's the point of the flippant answer. It's an infinite loop that keeps consing more functions and eventually runs out of memory.

Comment: I think the `let` form actually makes it more complicated to hand-evaluate `(Y Y)` and see that you end up with larger and larger terms made up of the same things. (Which is more or less what the book expects you to do.)

Comment: See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75687604/633183) for a detailed explanation of the U and Y combinators. Follow up with any questions ^^

Answer (score 3):

Maybe writing it in λ-calculus can help: Y = λ*f*.(λ*x*.*f*(*xx*))(λ*x*.*f*(*xx*)). It has the following β-reduction (aka execution):

Y*f* → *f*(Y*f*) → *f*(*f*(Y*f*)) → ...

Thus YY → Y(YY) → (YY)(Y(YY)) and you can keep on reducing, making the size of the term explode, as well as the number of arguments. Basically, you recursively apply to itself something that expects a function and applies it recursively...

Answer (score 1):

This is much easier to follow when throwing the combinators notation into the mix. Using

```ml
U x = x x       ; U = ^x. x x
```

your

```lisp
(define Y
  (lambda (le)
    ((lambda(f) (f f))
     (lambda(f)
       (le (lambda(x) ((f f) x)))))))
```

becomes

```ml
Y g = U (^f. g (^x. (f f) x))
```

and if we define

```ml
     H g f = g (^x. (f f) x)    = g (U f) = B g U f     ; H = CBU
```

we can then write it down as

```ml
Y g = U (H g)                                  ; Y = BUH = BU(CBU)
    = H g (H g)                                ; Y = SHH 
    = g (^x. ((H g) (H g)) x) 
    = g (^x. (Y g) x)

Y Y = Y (^x. (Y Y) x)
    = (^x. (Y Y) x) (^x. (Y (^x. (Y Y) x)) x)
    =      (Y Y)    (^x. (Y (^x. (Y Y) x)) x)
    = (^x. (Y Y) x) (^x. (Y (^x. (Y Y) x)) x) (^x. (Y (^x. (Y Y) x)) x)
    = ...
```

so, writing `Q` for `(^x. (Y (^x. (Y Y) x)) x)` we see that it's

```
Y Y = Y Y Q
    = Y Y Q Q
    = Y Y Q Q Q
    = Y Y Q Q Q Q
    = ...
```

and the reduction sequence never stops.